# Two-columns, 10pt bibliography / specific pages only, in a one-column, 12pt text body

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, two-column, multicol

For the writing of a document with a limited number of pages that I would like to keep easy to read and scheme over, I would like to have

- the main text in one column, 12pt
- the bibliography in two-columns, 10pt

Is this possible ? How to do that ?

N.B.: I know the multicol command is working well for the two-column / one-column change, but what about the 12 / 10 pt change ? Since the bibliography is not too long, I can eventually suppose it to be a specific page, and do some manual command locally if required.

Comment: You can add the `\small` command just before the bibliography, followed by `\normalsize` at the end of the bibliography. Or alternatively use the `\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont` combo, where the first size is the font size and the second is the baseline skip.

Comment: @guillem Thanks a lot, \small is working perfectly indeed. I thought it does not change the space between the lines. Actually it works perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: @guillem: How do you make sure the effects will be restricted to the bibliography only? Your suggestion assumes that code which comes before `\printbibliography` and after it in the *source* will also start being effective just before, and stop being effective just after it in the *output*. If you know a bit about TeX's output routine, or have ever worked with, for example, floats, you won't be surprised to hear that something like `\small\printbibliography\normalsize` is gonna backfire sooner or later. That's why there's things like `\bibsetup`.

Comment: @NilsL Thanks for pointing out the possible problems of my "solution". I don't know much (if anything) of TeX output routine and wasn't fully aware of the difference between _source_ and _output_.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{biblatex,lipsum,multicol}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\appto{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
\appto{\bibsetup}{\raggedright}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printbibliography
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

@Andrew: I usually try to keep the amount of explanation I add to my code in a relation to the amount and helpfulness of the information provided by the person asking the question (think of who's providing the MWE here, and who [should](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) be).  But since you're asking... :-)

So this code mainly relies on biblatex's `\bibsetup` and `\bibfont`, which is the probably the safest (and most elegant) way to customize a bibliography's style. I'm appending `\footnotesize` (that's 10pt in a 12pt environment) to whatever else is already contained in `\bibfont`. I'm also switching to a right rag, which is a nice thing in bibliographies, and a must when working with columns that narrow. Then there's `multicols`, restricted to the bibliography only. One might also try using `\twocolumn` and `\onecolumn` instead of the multicol package.

```
\appto{\bibsetup}{\raggedright\twocolumn}
\AtEndBibliography{\onecolumn}
```

Un-tested, though.

Comment: +1 The answer would be better if you explained your code.

Comment: @NilsL Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. SO biblatex is my friend up to now :-)